# TextBox: Index was outside the bounds of the Array

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In my visual studio form, anytime I want to call a function based on a certain TextBox change of input, it throws an exception that  "Index was outside the bounds of the array", even though my code doesn't use that input to access any array.

```
If (TextBox8.Text <> "" And TextBox9.Text <> "") Then
  If (ComboBox9.Text = "DC / Single Phase") Then
    voltageDrop = CInt(TextBox9.Text) * (2 * CInt(TextBox8.Text) * resLen(ComboBox8.SelectedIndex) / 1000)
  Else
    voltageDrop = 1.732 * CInt(TextBox9.Text) * (CInt(TextBox8.Text) * resLen(ComboBox8.SelectedIndex) / 1000)
  End If
  Label54.Text = CStr(voltageDrop)
End If
```

TextBox8 is causing the problem.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is IndexOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: it looks to me like the value in ComboBox.SelectedIndex is larger than the length of the resLen array.

Comment: @Jeremy Yea that seems like the obvious answer, but I'm not sure why it would be, considering it's initialized to a valid value within the combobox list.

Comment: It's just weird that the TextBox input makes the exception get thrown, not the ComboBox input.

Comment: I'm assuming this code is inside a text_changed event, so when textbox8 changes, it references the selectedindex property of combobox 8. If nothing is selected in the combobox, selectedindex will be -1, which is out of bounds. Again, just psychic debugging. Don't know if this is your actual problem.

Comment: If I change the code to resLen(1) it works, so that must be the problem. Maybe I am not initializing the selected index correctly.

Comment: You need an if statement of `If ComboBox8.SelectedIndex > -1 Then`.

Comment: I'd suggest performing a Debug.WriteLine(Combo8.SelectedIndex) and Debug.WriteLine(resLen.Length) in there somewhere so you can see your  values. also remember that the array is zero based, so you may be giving it a value one larger than the end of the array allows.

Comment: @LarsTech Yep that did it. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I think in your if condition you have use wrong condition. may be you should use

```
textbox8.textchanged method()
```

Or you can use

```
textbox8.text!=""
```

Comment: Isn't '<>' Visual Basic syntax for not equal?